# Spring Dev Tools not Restarting After Making Changes in IntelliJ

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am building some backend APIs using Spring Boot and **Kotlin**.

My build tool is **Gradle**

My IDE is **IntelliJ Ultimate Edition** on a **Windows Machine**

I have included the spring boot dev tools into my `build.gradle.kts` dependencies as follow:

```
dependencies {
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
}
```

But whenever I make a change while the server is running, it doesn't automatically reflect the changes.

Is there anything else I need to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enable “Build project automatically” option in compiler settings.

Comment: I have already done that, but it's still not working.

Comment: I tried setting compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running enabled and it worked when application is running is Intelij itself.   If you run application from command line then without this setting also application will restart automatically.

Comment: Did you use Gradle or Maven? I am using Gradle and Kotlin and it doesn't work.

Comment: Now, try with Gradle. It's surprising it doesn't work with gradle

Answer (score 0):

**1 - You need to enable the “Make project automatically” option:**

You can find it in `Settings` –> `Build, Execution, Deployment –> Compiler`

**2 - Changes in IntelliJ registory:**

Go to `Cmd+Shift+A (Mac)` or `Ctrl+Shift+A (Windows)` -> `Registry Enable` `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running`

[image]

Comment: I have enabled ```compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running``` and yet still not working. I have discovered that this works well if I am using maven pom.xml but once I use gradle, it doesn't work

Comment: Configuration with gradle is available here, I think it will solve the problem. See https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-dev-tools/